# What does joining with on a table twice on column as different aliases mean?

Tags: sql, database

I only know basic SQL but the project that I am working on uses pretty complex queries. There is one query that I can't understand. The tables and fields of concern are `people` and `person_details` and the executable part of an even dirtier query is:

```
SELECT people.first_name
    , people.last_name
    , person_statuses.name as person_status
    , companies.name as company_name
    , person_roles.name as role 
    , person_role_memberships.event_name as membership_year
    , person_role_memberships.start_date as start_date
    , person_role_memberships.end_date as end_date
    , person_role_memberships.sponsor_parent_company as sponsor_parent_company
    , person_role_memberships.former_sponsor_parent_company as former_sponsor_parent_company
    , person_role_memberships.workshop as workshop
FROM people
    , *person_details as business_details*
    , *person_details*
    , person_roles
    ,  person_role_memberships
    , companies
    , person_statuses
    , companies as parent_companies
WHERE person_role_memberships.person_id = people.id 
    AND person_role_memberships.person_role_id = person_roles.id 
    AND
```

```
    business_details.type = 'BusinessDetail' 
    and business_details.person_id = people.id 
    AND person_details.type = 'PersonalDetail' 
    and person_details.person_id = people.id
```

```
    AND people.person_status_id = person_statuses.id 
    AND ifnull(companies.parent_id, companies.id) = parent_companies.id  
    AND people.company_id = companies.id 
    AND companies.name = 'Pak Qatar' 
    AND people.last_name = 'Aslam' 
limit 100;
```

I want to know what is the logic that the bold part of the `where` clause is creating. Is it, because of the `AND` keyword, only allowing those persons, which have BusinessDetail as well as PersonalDetails is the `person_details` table?

Comment: please use proper JOIN syntax instead commas and use table aliases to make your SQL cleaner

Comment: I so would. The whole project is full of complex queries like this, I am just adding small features and removing bugs from an already built project. But I haven't got the time (or willingness) to correct someone's mess.

Comment: @Jamie: if a programmer is tasked with making a particular change he should not take it upon himself to change other things outside the scope of the project.  That means it would be a first order mistake for the OP to decide to rewrite working SQL in a production system to make it "cleaner".  The OP is trying to learn what an existing query does, not how to write better queries from scratch.

Comment: @Larry, yes, I agree. I should have clarified: My comment was simply directed at adding line breaks to the code (meaningless in SQL syntax.) It was originally shared as three lines without breaks.

Comment: @Jamie: My apologies.  I thought you were amplifying bluefeet's remark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically saying:

The person MUST have a business_details record which MUST be of type 'BusinessDetails' AND the person MUST have a person_details record which MUST be of the type 'PersonalDetail' It looks like both are stored in the same table (business_details is an alias of the person_details table), so its joining to the table twice to check for both conditions.

I'm not sure what flavour of SQL this is (SQL Server/Oracle etc) but the query could probably be written out a little neater using proper join syntax (although the syntax used will create joins under the hood, its not as easy to read as something with explicit join syntax).

Comment: Thanks Tim. Would the condition be false even if any one of the details is missing in the table? Either PersonalDetails or BusinessDetails?

Comment: If one of the details was missing, the row would be excluded from the results, BOTH have to be present to show up in the results.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a self join. It's usually used when you have a relation (table) relating with itself (`employees <-> boss`), or when a relation (table) is used to store different kind of information for a certain row.

In your example, table `person_details` is being used to store **business** and **person** information. The join is:

```
business_details.person_id = people.id 
AND person_details.type = 'PersonalDetail' 
AND person_details.person_id = people.id
```

So I would say that `person_details` table holds business **and** person information on different rows for the same `people.id` row in `people` table.

Comment: Sorry if I said I know basic SQL. I don't get what you said. Do you mean person_details table is related to itself?

Comment: Okay - so my question was - what kinda logic does this apply? What would this query read in simple English, I meant to ask.